# How to make the KendoUI Edit button work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

KendoUI has certain widgets that only seem to work in Firefox and not in Chrome. 
Like the Edit command button in a grid.

```
     { command: [ { name: "Edit" ,text:'', imageClass: "k-icon k-i-pencil", 
                               click: function(e) {
                                   //some code
                               }
```

On clicking the function isn't called at all in Chrome but works perfectly in Firefox.

Is there anyway I can fix it to make it work in both browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Bind your `inline` grid like this,

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    navigatable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 430,
                    groupable: {
                        messages: {
                            empty: "Drop columns here"
                        }
                    },
                    toolbar: ["create"],
                    columns: [
                                    "ProductName",

                                    {field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", width: 110 },
                                    { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110 },
                                    { field: "Discontinued", width: 110 },
                                    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: 190}],

                    editable: "inline"
                });
```

Grid Command

`{ command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: 190}]` it working on both chrome and FF.

Comment: Mine is a custom edit command. I am not using inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

This demo seems to be working in all browsers:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/custom-command.html